# Good data structure for euclidean 3d data queries?

Tags: data-structures, 3d

What's a good way to store point cloud data so that it's optimal for an application that will do one of these two queries?

1. Nearest (i.e. lowest euclidean distance) data point to (x,y,z)
2. Get all the points inside a sphere with radius R around a point (x,y,z)

The structure will only be filled once, but read many times. A lowish memory footprint would be nice as I may be dealing with datasets of > 7 million points, but speed should be of primary concern. A library would be nice, but I wouldn't mind implementing it myself if it's something doable with limited expertise in the area.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [Kd-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree)  you get O(log(*n*)) nearest neighbor, and usually range queries will be fast.

There are a bunch of libraries referenced there.  I have not used any of them.

You might also look at [CGAL](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Spatial_searching/Chapter_main.html).  I have used CGAL for other things, it is tolerably fast, extremely comprehensive, but the documentation will drive you to drink.

Comment: There are links to implementations on the wiki page, I have not tried any of them though.  kD trees are pretty easy to implement, particularly if you are not adding and removing points (it seems that you aren't)

Answer (score 1):

A huge portion of the decision in data structures will depend on the spatial organization of the data.  For example, highly clustered data tends to have different performance charateristics in kd-trees than evenly distributed data.

[KD-Trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree) are very good for both of these queries.

[Octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) can be a good option in many cases, as well, and is potentially easier to implement.

There are many libraries out there that do this, using various algorithms.  Searching for [k-nearest neighbor searching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) will reveal many useful libraries.  I've had pretty good luck with [ANN](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/) in the past, for example.

Comment: ANN seems interest, I'll give it a look as well. Thanks!

Comment: @Xzhsh: STANN is another good one, btw.  I think they even have an ANN wrapper, so you can try multiple algorithms with one codebase...